# Rails friendly_id gem not working with link_to helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I’ve set the friendly_id gem up, and generated slugs for my model.

The slugs are all shown in my DB column, and if I run Event.friendly.find('my-event-name') in the console, it works perfectly.

My URL’s are still showing as organisation/1/events/1 though, when I check the result of the following link_to:-

```
<%= link_to organisation_event_path(event.organisation.id, event.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' do %>
```

I’ve also added

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

to my model.

When I visit the URL manually, it works with the friendly id - so it seems to be just the link_to helper that isn't working.

Could possibly be related to some additional setup required for nested routes here - but I can’t seem to find anything when I search.

```
  resources :organisations do
    resources :events
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is way more explicit then you need to be. As long as you're following the conventions you can let them do the work for you:

```
<%= link_to [event.organisation, event], class: 'btn btn-primary do %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Under the covers rails will look up the `organisation_event_path` helper (by looking at the model names) - and call its `to_param` method.

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be that I need to change the `.id` in my link_to, to `.friendly_id` like so:-

```
<%= link_to organisation_event_path(event.organisation.id, event.friendly_id), class: 'btn btn-primary' do %>
```

Would expected it to work without this but perhaps not.

Comment: @max 's answer is better.  You shouldn't specify any id or friendly_id fields and it will work intrinsically.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that defeat the purpose of the helper then?  I like being able to specify the helper path to make it more readable.

Comment: No it doesn't - the polymorphic routing uses the helper anyways. As far as more readible - thats a matter of opinion but this is really just more noise.

Comment: The helper is still usable, just do `organisation_event_path(event.organisation, event)`